# A thin line appears when the keyboard dismisses - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-keyboard

I am new to SwiftUI, and I am creating a simple view which contains 3 textfields and a button.
When I focus on a textfield the keyboard appears and it moves the view upwards, then when I dismiss the keyboard , the view is moved downwards to its original position, however when this happens a thin line appears then disappears for a fraction of a second.

Any help regarding this matter is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` on your view embedding the textfield (not the textfield itself), and let the view take the whole space by adding `Spacer()` to the bottom of your view.